# what might be the reason for this syntax error

Tags: javascript, php

I have some php code inside script tag.But i am getting an error for some of my lines.can't figure out why it is giving error.

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

```
<script>
var item_container=document.getElementById('item-container');
<?php if(isset($item_count)){ ?>
   var item_count=<?php echo $item_count; }?>;
var no_of_column=Math.ceil(item_count/3);
var item_container_width=item_container.offsetWidth;
var each_column_width=(item_container_width/no_of_column)-3+'px';
for(i=0;i<no_of_column;i++){

        var column_div="<div style='border:1px solid red;height:100%;width:"+each_column_width+";float:left;position:relative;'></div>";

        item_container.innerHTML+=column_div;
}

<?php if(isset($items)){ foreach($items as $item){?>

         item_container.firstChild.innerHTML+="<input type='checkbox' name='item' value='item1'>"+<?php echo $item->Item_Type; ?>+"</br>";

<?php 
        }
    }
?>
</script>
```

if i omit the following lines the error is gone.

```
 <?php if(isset($items)){ foreach($items as $item){?>

             item_container.firstChild.innerHTML+="<input type='checkbox' name='item' value='item1'>"+<?php echo $item->Item_Type; ?>+"</br>";

    <?php 
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: specify the error too.

Comment: Why is your js and php together inside `<script></script>` ? kinda curious

Comment: you are mixing php and js lot of time and messed completly

Comment: he might have a reason for that.. lets wait for his reason for mixing php and js

Comment: `item_container.firstChild.innerHTML+='<input type="checkbox" name="item" value="item1">'+<?php echo $item->Item_Type; ?>+'</br>';
` try this come.

Comment: Above might not work. Try specify your $items to js variable and instead of foreach , try with "for loop"of javascript.

Comment: Is `$item->Item_Type` a string?

Comment: I am not sure but may be like ths you want:- https://eval.in/595381 . check code only and also variables value is up-to-you. you have to handle them

Comment: You do **not** provide the necessary information to enable people to give an accurate answer. You will "earn" down votes if you do not expose what the content of `$item->Item_Type` actually is. It might be a simple string or executable JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a solution.It is assign each row values in an object literal and then traverse the object and assign its property values to a check box.

```
  var item_container=document.getElementById('item-container');
    <?php if(isset($item_count)){ ?>
    var item_count=<?php echo $item_count; }?>;
    var no_of_column=Math.ceil(item_count/3);
    var item_container_width=item_container.offsetWidth;
    var each_column_width=(item_container_width/no_of_column)-3+'px';
    for(i=0;i<no_of_column;i++){

        var column_div="<div style='height:100%;width:"+each_column_width+";float:left;position:relative;'></div>";

        item_container.innerHTML+=column_div;
    }

        var array_holder=[];
        <?php if(isset($items)){foreach($items as $item){?>
                 var obj={
                     id  :"<?php echo $item->Type_id; ?>",
                     item:"<?php echo $item->Item_Type; ?>"

                 };
               array_holder.push(obj);
        <?php
                    }
                }
        ?>

        var only_divs=item_container.getElementsByTagName('div');
        var array_counter=0;
        var column_index=0;
        array_holder.forEach(function(element,index,array){

            if(array_counter<3){
                   only_divs[column_index].innerHTML+=  "<li style='margin-left:5px;margin-top:3px;'><input type='checkbox' style='outline:1px solid blue;' name='item' value='"+element.id+"'>"+element.item+"</li></br>";

                   array_counter++;
            }else{
                column_index++;
                only_divs[column_index].innerHTML+=  "<li style='margin-left:5px;margin-top:3px;'><input type='checkbox' style='outline:1px solid blue;' name='item' value='item1'>"+element.item+"</li></br>";
                array_counter=0;
            }
        });

        only_divs[0].innerHTML+=  "<li style='margin-left:5px;margin-top:3px;'><input type='checkbox' style='outline:1px solid blue;' name='item' value='0'>other</li></br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$item->Item_Type` is a string value then the problem (or *a* problem) is that you are concatenating it without putting quotation marks. So if the type is, say `"red thing"`, the code the browser sees is:

```
item_container.firstChild.innerHTML+=
  "<input type='checkbox' name='item' value='item1'>"+red thing+"</br>";
```

...which is of course a syntax error because `red` isn't a variable and even if it was you couldn't then just have `thing` without a semicolon first.

You should be able to just embed that PHP echo directly in the string:

```
item_container.firstChild.innerHTML+=
  "<input type='checkbox' name='item' value='item1'><?php echo $item->Item_Type; ?></br>";

// note that the "+ and +" is gone from here ------^-------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no dynamic code to be executed in the PHP generated peace, you can just insert the string directly. However, you should escape backslashes and double quotes, since your JavaScript code does use double quotes as delimiters and backslashes in JavaScript strings are considered as escape code to the succeeding character.

```
 item_container.firstChild.innerHTML+="<input type='checkbox' name='item' value='item1'><?php echo str_replace([ '\\', '"'], [ '\\\\', '\\"'], $item->Item_Type); ?></br>";
```